# Disc brake lines quite long

Tags: disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, cable-routing

Currently building a new mountain bike. I'm fairly bike savvy and have built quite a few bikes over the years, but mainly road bikes.

I have installed/fitted a new Shimano slx group set and the hydraulic brake housing is very long. Lots of excess brake line around the handlebars, and when looking at other bikes in the shop they don't seem to have that problem. I'm fairly sure you can't shorten the housing, and not sure I want to have a crack at that if that is the case, so I wanted to see how other people get around this problem?

Comment: Cables can be shortened, if you're not comfortable around disc brakes shops can usually do it for about an hours work.

Comment: Cheers, it is a dupe.

Normally I would have a crack but seeing as they're brand new I don't really want to take the risk, plus for an hours work I'll take it in.